# [R][package] Load all functions in a package's NAMESPACE

Tags: r, namespaces, r-package

**Tl;dr**

I have a complete NAMESPACE file for the package I am building. I want to execute all the importFrom(x,y) clauses in that file to get the set of necessary functions I use in the package. Is there an automated way to do that?

**Full question**

I'm currently working on building a package that in turns depends on a bunch of other packages. Think: both Hmisc and dplyr.

The other contributors to the package don't really like using devtools::build() every 5 minutes when they debug, which I can understand. They want to be able to toggle a dev_mode boolean which, when set to true, loads all dependencies and sources all scripts in the R/ and data-raw/ folders, so that all functions and data objects are loaded in memory. I don't necessarily think that's a perfectly clean solution, but they're technically my clients and it's a big help to them so please don't offer a frame challenge unless it's the most user-friendly solution imaginable.

The problem with this solution is that when I load two libraries whose namespace clash, functions in the package that would perfectly work otherwise start throwing errors. I thus need to improve my import system.

Thanks to thorough documentation (and the help of devtools::check()), my NAMESPACE is complete. I guess I could split it in pieces and eval() some well-chosen parts of it, but it sort of feels like I'm probably not the first person to encounter this difficulty. Is there an automated way to parse NAMESPACE and import the proper functions from the proper packages ?

Thanks !

Comment: I may be misunderstanding what you mean, but wouldn't `devtools::load_all()` do what you want?

Comment: It seems to be 1- fast 2- doing what I want. If you put that as an answer I'll accept it. Thanks!!